# Static non-moving texture

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I have a constantly moving from right to left plane with repeating texture on it. My goal is to make texture stay at constant position on screen while plane continues moving. How to do that using shader? or without shader

Answer (score 0):

If you minus the amount your plane moves in the x,y from your texture coordinates (keeping it in the [0 1] range still, probably not essential though if you have a repeating texture), that should theoretically keep your texture stationary while the plane moves. Will also probably depend on the distance the plane is from the camera as well, just play around with it till it looks right.